# Elastic search Query - in array of objects

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-nested

I have created an Index with 100+ documents, here are the sample 2 documents

Document 1:

> "OfficeId": 1, "Officename": "Washers Ltd", "customers": [
>
> ```
> {
>     "customerid":10,
>     "customername": Mike,
>     "customerphone": 1111111111
> }
> ,
> {
>     "customerid":20,
>     "customername": Angie,
>     "customerphone": 2222222222
> } ]
> ```

Document 2:

> "OfficeId": 2, "Officename": "Coldwell Ltd", "customers": [
>
> ```
> {
>     "customerid":30,
>     "customername": Nathan,
>     "customerphone": 1111111111
> } ]
> ```

From the UI we can search by customername or customerphone. When I am searching by phone **1111111111** I should be getting the 2 documents (hit 0, hit 1) but in the first document/hit 0, how I can filter only to display 1 object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [nested query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-nested-query.html) along with [inner_hits](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/search-request-inner-hits.html)

Adding a working example with index data, mapping, search query and search result

**Index Mapping:**

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "customers": {
        "type": "nested"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Index Data:**

```
{
  "OfficeId": 2,
  "Officename": "Coldwell Ltd",
  "customers": [
    {
      "customerid": 30,
      "customername": "Nathan",
      "customerphone": 1111111111
    }
  ]
}
{
  "OfficeId": 1,
  "Officename": "Washers Ltd",
  "customers": [
    {
      "customerid": 10,
      "customername": "Mike",
      "customerphone": 1111111111
    },
    {
      "customerid": 20,
      "customername": "Angie",
      "customerphone": 2222222222
    }
  ]
}
```

**Search Query:**

```
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "customers",
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "match": {
                "customers.customerphone": "1111111111"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "inner_hits": {}
    }
  }
}
```

Search Result will be

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "67228476",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 1.0,
        "_source": {
          "OfficeId": 1,
          "Officename": "Washers Ltd",
          "customers": [
            {
              "customerid": 10,
              "customername": "Mike",
              "customerphone": 1111111111
            },
            {
              "customerid": 20,
              "customername": "Angie",
              "customerphone": 2222222222
            }
          ]
        },
        "inner_hits": {
          "customers": {
            "hits": {
              "total": {
                "value": 1,
                "relation": "eq"
              },
              "max_score": 1.0,
              "hits": [
                {
                  "_index": "67228476",
                  "_type": "_doc",
                  "_id": "1",
                  "_nested": {
                    "field": "customers",
                    "offset": 0
                  },
                  "_score": 1.0,
                  "_source": {
                    "customerid": 10,           // note this
                    "customername": "Mike",
                    "customerphone": 1111111111
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "67228476",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "2",
        "_score": 1.0,
        "_source": {
          "OfficeId": 2,
          "Officename": "Coldwell Ltd",
          "customers": [
            {
              "customerid": 30,
              "customername": "Nathan",      
              "customerphone": 1111111111
            }
          ]
        },
        "inner_hits": {
          "customers": {
            "hits": {
              "total": {
                "value": 1,
                "relation": "eq"
              },
              "max_score": 1.0,
              "hits": [
                {
                  "_index": "67228476",
                  "_type": "_doc",
                  "_id": "2",
                  "_nested": {
                    "field": "customers",
                    "offset": 0
                  },
                  "_score": 1.0,
                  "_source": {
                    "customerid": 30,       // note this
                    "customername": "Nathan",
                    "customerphone": 1111111111
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    ]
```

**Update 1:**

If you want to include one more `match` clause, use this query

```
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "customers",
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "match": {
                "customers.customerphone": "1111111111"
              }
            },
            {
              "match": {
                "customers.customername": "Nathan"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "inner_hits": {}
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for responding immediately. One more question, we don't know how they will be searching from the UI, they can search by customerphone or customername. In the given query, under "must" can i include one more "match" for customername ? @ESCoder

Comment: @RKGaz yes you can include one more `match` clause

Comment: @RKGaz updated the answer, with one more query. Please go through that and let me know if this resolves your issue ?

Comment: In my mapping, I didn't mention ** "type": "nested"**. I will include that and recreate the index again.

Comment: Sorry, this is my first post and first work on Elastic search. I will definitely keep you posted once it resolves the issue.

Comment: @RKGaz no issue :-) Recreate the index and use the search queries given in the answer.

Comment: unfortunately I don't have access to remove the Index, I asked another person to delete and recreate the Index. But I have modified the query and gave a try, but I still got the same results(I can see customerId 20 in the response).


I assume it's because in my Index I didn't mention the "type": "nested" :), Please correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: @RKGaz yes you need to have a `nested` type for the `customers` field. Then only you would be able to retrieve the matching document in the `inner_hits` section

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked. Can you please point me to where I can download any tool/something to test ES on my local windows machine?

Comment: sorry forgot to update, in the query we changed from "must" to "should".

Comment: @RKGaz You can download postman --> https://www.postman.com/downloads/. This will help you to test and run the elasticsearch queries